# Ecplise - Run as Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse and want to run a programm but I'm not able to do this. There's no "Run as Java Application" available. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Right-click on your main class, Run As-->Java Application .

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add a new run configuration: Run -> Run Configurations ... -> Select "Java Appliction" and click "New".